# Property i18n is not allowed

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

When localizing angular application and adding properties in angular.json file it gives the following warnings.

Under project: **Property i18n is not allowed.**

```
"i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "en-US",
    "locales": {
        "ru": "src/i18n/messages.ru.xlf"
    }
}
```

Under project/architect/build/configurations: **Property localize is not allowed.**

```
"ru": {
    "localize": ["ru"]
}
```

Meanwhile, ng serve provides this error.

```
Data path ".projects['xxx']" should NOT have additional properties(i18n).
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code example as a starting point, for example, an Angular project in https://stackblitz.com/. It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use localization tutorial for Angular 9 (or higher), but your current repository is Angular 8 (or lower).